# How can I make a triple foreach faster?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, cakephp, view

I have this http://pastebin.com/4NYvuaB0 view with the following result:

[image]

The first foreach iteracts with projects
the second iterates over Hitos (One project has one or more Hitos)
the third iterates over Tareas (One Hito has zero, one or more tareas)

It's working ok, but it takes about 120 seconds to render the view, which is too much!

Does someone have an idea of how to make it faster?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would first suggest to use a template system like smarty etc. Than you have separated code from HTML...that will make things simpler. And an other question is:How fast is it at the moment? measured results ?

Comment: Please, if you expect anyone else to read your close, name everything (classes, functions, variables, comments) in English. I'm by far not a native English spearker myself, but just like medics name things in latin we name things in English. Not for aesthetic reasons, but so other have a chance to read it too.

Comment: @khmarbaise: CakePHP views with PHP in it is a templating system. You can use it wrong of course by putting logic into it. There is no point to use templating with PHP, because PHP code can be inserted into the HTML templates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should limit the use of class $semaforo leveraging on css

Change the range attribution, the one you have now is a bit confusing:

```
function semColor($p) {
    $semValues = array('rojo','berde','amarillo','naranja','rojo');
    $ranges = array(-1,50,70,100);
    for ($i=0; $i<4;$i++)
        if ($ranges[$i]>$p['desv']) break;
    return $semValues[$i];
}
```

use a template to create a row

```
/* use any other method to create the template string */
$templ = '<div class="%s %s"><ul><li class="thmas">&nbsp;<a href="#" class="trigger2">&nbsp;</a></li>'
       . '<li class="'
       . join('">%s&nbsp;</li><li class="', 
             array_merge(array('','th1','th2','th3','th5','th4','th6'),
             array_fill(0,12,'thmes'),
             array('thtotal','thtotal)
       )).'">%s&nbsp;</li></ul></div>';
```

your code for the inner loop become:

```
foreach ( $aTareak as $a ) {
   if (($a['proyecto_id']==$h['proyecto_id']) && ($a['hito_id']==$h['hito_id'])) {
      printf($templ, 
         'divtrtarea',
         semColor($a['desv'])
         $a['categoria_nombre'],
         $a['coordinador_nombre'],
         $a['tarea_nombre'],
         $a['total_prev'],
         $a['total_horas'],
         round($a['desv'], 2),
         $a['1'], $a['2'], $a['3'], $a['4'], $a['5'], $a['6'],
         $a['7'], $a['8'], $a['9'], $a['10'], $a['11'], $a['12'],
         array_sum(array_slice($a,1,12)), /* assuming they are consecutive */
         $html->link('Selec.',array(
           'controller'=>'lineas',
           'action'=>'addhoras', 
           $a['proyecto_id'],
           $a['hito_id'],
           $a['tarea_id'])
         )
      );
   }
}
```

the outer ones have to change accordingly

Comment: Thak you very much! It was very helpfull!

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear where does **$proiektuak** come from.

How many rows do you want to display at one time?
If many, try to limit them.

It would be much easier to give an advise if we knew where does the bottleneck appear.

Comment: $proiektuak is an array I popullated on the controller. The bottlenek is rendering this view.. it tooks to much time but there is nothing to limit because I need all rows